# C++ How to use less conditional statements?

Tags: c++, string, conditional-statements

For my assignment, I'm storing user login infos. I'm taking in a string which is the command. The command can be create, login, remove, etc. There are 10 total options, i.e 10 different strings possible. Can anyone explain a more efficient way to write this instead of 10 if and else if statements? Basically how should I format/structure things besides using a bunch of `if (string == "one")`, `else if (string == "two")`. Thank you

Comment: presumably you mean `==` rather than `=`. You could make a lookup table, but if you have 10 different pieces of code to execute then there is really no way to get around writing 10 pieces of code!

Comment: so if the strings can be "create", "clear", "login", etc. I have to have different conditional statements for each?

Comment: Yes, or you have to store them in a table

Comment: If you have numerous command options that can change during the life of your application then a flexible option is to use a map or hashtable mapping commands to the functions or function-like objects you want to call - but for 10 fixed options I'd probably just use `if/else` for simplicity/readability.

Comment: Maybe you can create a `std::map<std::string, int>` and use map lookups to get the code of the command that was passed - you can later switch on that number. Or create an `enum Command` and have a `std::map<std::string, Command>` & use the switch.

Comment: The table / hash-switch / etc. solutions have a lot of boilerplate to get them going, so I wouldn't bother unless you were going to have at least 20 cases (and plan for easy adding/removal in future)

Comment: no doubt someone will come along and post a `map` of string to lambda

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map which does the comparison for you.

Something like this:

**Initialise map:**

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string&)>> map;
map["login"]  = std::bind(&Class::DoLogin,  this, std::placeholders::_1);
map["create"] = std::bind(&Class::DoCreate, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

**Receive message:**

```
map.at(rx.msg_type)(rx.msg_data);
```

**Handler:**

```
void Class::DoLogin(const std::string& data)
{
   // do login
}
```

Comment: ITT `std::placesholders`

Comment: Haha, yes, they hold the places! Erm, typo :)

Answer (score 1):

I expect that your lecturer would like you to extract function to another re-usable function:

```
string action;
command = CreateAction(action);
command.Do(...);
```

Ofcourse, inside you CreateAction class you still need to have the conditionals that determine which commands need to be created.

```
AbstractCommand CreateAction(action)
{
    if (action == "login")
        return LoginCommand();
    else if (action == "remove")
        return RemoveCommand();
    ..... etc etc
}
```

And if you really want to get rid of all the conditionals than you can create some self-registering commands but that involves a lot more code and classes......

You should look up things like [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

You can use function pointers and a lookup table.

```
typedef void (*Function_Pointer)(void);
void Create(void);
void Login(void);
void Remove(void);

struct Function_Option_Entry
{
  const char * option_text;
  Function_Pointer p_function;
};

Function_Option_Entry option_table[] =
{
  {"one", Create},
  {"two", Login},
  {"three", Remove},
};
const unsigned int option_table_size =
  sizeof(option_table) / sizeof(option_table[0]);

//...
std::string option_text;
//...
for (i = 0; i < option_table_size; ++i)
{
  if (option_text == option_table[i].option_text)
  {
    option_table[i].p_function();
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `switch`, and a simple hash-function.
You need to use a hash-function, because C and C++ only allow switching on integral values.

```
template<size_t N> constexpr char myhash(const char &x[N]) { return x[0] ^ (x[1]+63); }
char myhash(const string& x) { return x.size() ? x[0] ^ (x[1]+63) : 0; }

switch(myhash(s)) {
case myhash("one"):
    if(s != "one") goto nomatch;
    // do things
    break;
case myhash("two"):
    if(s != "two") goto nomatch;
    // do things
    break;
default:
nomatch:
    // No match
}
```

Slight adjustments are needed if you are not using `std::string`.

Comment: nice hash idea, +1, although `goto` should be prohibited from C/C++ :) In the current code it's ok, but users' abuse create nightmares.

Comment: @vsoftco: Thanks. I'm solidly in the camp for using the right tool for the job, even if that should be the dreaded `goto`. (And yes, the given one *is* an appropriate use.) Always remember Djikstra wrote that famous article when structured programming (using anything *but* `goto`) was just getting started (and yes, that means he used a little hyperbole, though not much).

Comment: Good idea, but will your hash function work with a string which contains only one symbol?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I mean you just check that length is not a zero and then straight go for x[1]. If size of a string equals to 1 it can cause a problem. Or not?

Comment: @Anton: The template will work with any string but the empty string (UB or ill-formed, depends), for which the other one returns 0. Trivially to fix if you want to allow an empty string too. BTW: If the hash-function is not a perfect hash for the input, the switch is ill-formed.

Comment: @Anton: `std::string`s have a 0-terminator, which is not part of the length.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a function for every specific string. For example, if you receive a string "create" you will call function doCreate(), if you receive a string "login" then you call function doLogin()

The only restriction on these function is that all of them must have the same signature. In an example above it was smh like this:

```
typedef void (*func_t) ();
```

The idea is to create a std::map from strings to these functions. So you wouldn't have to write 10 if's or so because you will be able to simple choose the right function from the map by the name of a specific string name. Let me explain it by the means of a small example:

```
typedef void (*func_t) ();
void doCreate()
{
     std::cout << "Create function called!\n";
}

void doLogin()
{
     std::cout << "Login function called!\n";
}

std::map<std::string, func_t> functionMap;

void initMap()
{
    functionMap["create"] = doCreate;
    functionMap["login"] = doLogin;
}

int main()
{
     initMap();
     std::string str = "login";
     functionMap[str](); // will call doLogin()

     str = "create";
     functionMap[str](); // will call doCreate()

     std::string userStr;
     // let's now assume that we also can receive a string not from our set of functions
     std::cin >> userStr;
     if (functionMap.count(userStr))
     {
          functionMap[str](); // now we call doCreate() or doLogin()
     }
     else
     {
          std::cout << "Unknown command\n";
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

I hope it will help you in someway=)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Trouble is, we have a crash in the default-case. Which is probably not wanted, as the data is user-supplied and not pre-vetted. Also I doubt it's more efficient (OPs wish).

Comment: @Deduplicator: I think that default case is not a really big problem and can be solved by adding a small check. About efficiency... Actually I might not understand OP right, but in my opinion it is more a question about scalability and readability then about efficiency. Anyway, does it really cost that much?

Comment: If efficiency is a major concern you could use unordered_map

Comment: @SteveLorimer: Is it really faster then std::map? I mean theoretically - of course yes. But if the size of a dictionary is less then a hundred... Actually I agree with Deduplicator and do believe that his answer provides the most efficient solution.

Comment: @Deduplicator's may be the most efficient, strictly, but at a huge readability and maintenance cost.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I would debate the *huge* cost in readability and maintenance, though a slightly higher maintenance-cost than using a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` is certainly there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a `std::map<std::string, int>` and use map lookups to get the code of the command that was passed - you can later switch on that number. Or create an `enum Command` and have a `std::map<std::string, Command>` and use the switch.

Example:

```
enum Command
{
     CREATE,
     LOGIN,
     ...
};

std::map<std::string, Command> commandNameToCode;
// fill the map with appropriate values
commandNameToCode["create"] = Command::CREATE;

// somehow get command name from user and store in the below variable (not shown)    
std::string input;

// check if the command is in the map and if so, act accordingly
if(commandNameToCode.find(input) != commandNameToCode.end())
{
    switch(commandNameToCode[input])
    {
    case CREATE:
         // handle create
         break;
    ...
    }
}
```