# How do I select a variable based on an argument?

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment, wherein, I receive a list of strings as an argument in a function. Based on the strings contained in the list I have to do some processing on the records. The strings contained in the list correspond to the member variables in the Record class. The list argument however, may contain different number of strings each time doProcessing() is called. Given below is a simplified version of my code:

```
  class Record{
            string str1;
            string str2;
            ...
            string strn;
            }; // end Record class
 class Process{
          void doProcessing(Record* rec, set<string> strList){
           if(strList.find("abc") == rec->str1){
              //do something
              }
            if(strList.find("def") == rec->str2){
              //do something
              }
               ........
           }
       }; // end Process class
```

Here, strList differs each time doProcessing is called. It may contain only 1 string or n strings depending upon the situation.

I believe there is a flaw in the design itself. Please suggest a good design to handle this scenario. I own all the classes, hence no issues in design changes.

Comment: Can you check the documentation regarding what `set<String>::find` returns in different scenarios (element exists/doesn't exist)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Forcing functions into classes does not make procedural code object-oriented.
   Why is `doProcessing` not a free function?
2. Use references instead of pointers when the parameter is not optional, nor an array.
3. Consider iterating through the set, and [using a `switch` for string-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139247/c-how-to-use-less-conditional-statements/27139462#27139462).
4. Are you sure the data-types in the record are right, and you aren't just falling into the trap of [stringly-typed programming](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)?
   Also consider using a `std::tuple` or `std::array` there.

There's a but too: [`std::set.find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) returns an iterator.